# How to make a jquery multiple filter system for every column of table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I have to make a multiple filter system in jquery, but i have to verify that text that i will enter in a text box, is equal with an element from table. For example if I enter a name, John, i need all rows in table with student name John. If i will write Joh, i need only rows with student name Joh. And i need to apply multiple filters.

What i tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").click(function() {
    var value = $("#myInput").val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <button id="filter" type="button" name="filter">Sumbit</button>
  <br><br>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kim</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>kim@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>tim@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tanja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>tanja@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no element with ID *button*. Change `$("#button")` to `$("#filter")` and use `..$("#myInput").val()..` instead of `..$(this).val()..`

Comment: i tried to modify this, but it doesn't work, i tried only for first column, but i need for every column an input text to search

Comment: Take a look at https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

Comment: and if i write joh, this show me john, and i want to show only names joh

Comment: You filter the data rows but you did nothing on them. You should add some action(s) on the return rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").click(function() {
    var value = $("#myInput").val();
    $("#myTable tr").hide().filter(function() {
      let rgx = new RegExp("\\b"+value+"\\b", "i");
      let result = $(this).text().match(rgx);
      return result != null;
    }).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: it's ok, but i need when type a name to find this name. For example, now if i write Joh in this search bar, nothing will be displayed, but if i write a name from table, exactly this name, for example John, will display the row with name John. This is what i don't know how to do...

Comment: yes, exact match, and how could i filter with different input text every column ? for example a new <input> for column 2 a new <input> for filtering every column with exact match..

Comment: Thank You ! It works, and if you could help me, for find last name, no first name for example, what i need to change ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot a `"i"` parameter. Now it search the whole rows even the email field.